# Query to calculate delta MAU per month returns blank

Tags: sql

This is my query:

```
WITH mau_table AS (SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id) AS mau,
            DATE_TRUNC('month', order_date) :: DATE AS month_column
            FROM orders
            GROUP BY month_column)

SELECT (c.mau - p.mau) AS mau_delta,
        c.month_column
FROM mau_table AS c
      LEFT JOIN mau_table AS p
      ON c.month_column = p.month_column
      WHERE p.month_column = (c.month_column - INTERVAL '1 month') 

This is the table provided:
order_date  user_id order_id    meal_id order_quantity
2018-06-01  0   0   4   3
2018-06-01  0   0   14  2
2018-06-01  0   0   15  1
2018-06-01  0   0   17  1
2018-06-01  1   1   16  2
2018-06-01  1   1   17  1
2018-06-01  2   2   7   3
```

My query returns blank and i'm not sure why. My method was to join the table on itself on previous month = current month - 1 month

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what RMDBS you are using (Vertica, maybe?) but here is a solution with MariaDB which is a fork of MySQL. In your sample data, you don't have any data that would satisfy the clause, so there is no result. I don't know if your SQL Syntax is correct though.

Here is a example with some different sample data to show how it works.

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orders o1 ON o.user_id = o1.user_id
    AND extract(month FROM o.order_date) = extract(month FROM o1.order_date) - 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=d6d4528e8d53013d6f4612f7f68decb3